# Are other parties free to innovate on my invention?

Tags: licensing, novelty

If another party patents an invention which builds on my own, do they have to get a license from me before they can start manufacturing their product?  For example, if I invented the 'chair', and later someone comes up with the novel idea of a 'chair with inbuilt drink holder', can they go ahead an manufacture the 'chair with inbuilt drink holder' without permission from me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they use your patented invention, they need to obtain a license from you. If you want to use their improvement, you would need to obtain a license from them.